# Primary Key Insertion - SQLite with Objective-C

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'm trying to write user information to an SQLite database using Objective-C. I read on the SQLite website FAQ (http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) to enter NULL in place of the primary key, which I have done. However, I get the error code 20 (data type mismatch) when I perform `NSLog(@"%d",sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)`. Below is the relevant code.

Before anyone asks, I have appropriately opened the database in previous code, so that isn't the issue. writableDBPath is the path of the database, verified to be valid.

```
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    NSString *momentInsertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MomentTbl (momentID, albumID, title, timestamp, author, latitude, longitude, canvas) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",NULL, alb.ID, alb.title, m.timestamp, @"user", m.latitude, m.longitude, m.moment];
    const char *query_stmt = [momentInsertSQL UTF8String];
    const char *dbPath = [writableDBPath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, query_stmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);

            NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_step(sqlStatement));
            if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                NSLog(@"OK");
            else
                NSLog(@"Problem");

            sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }
```

When I replaced NULL with a number, the code returned was 101, which should be `SQLITE_DONE`, but NSLog still showed "Problem." Any help is appreciated, as someone who is new to SQLite I really need it.

Comment: Emm... you shouldn't be assigning values to your primary key!

Comment: So I should leave momentID and its corresponding value NULL out of my insert statement completely?

Comment: FYI - it's a terrible practice to build a query using `stringWithFormat`. Please do it the correct way (using the various `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL `NULL` is different from C `NULL`.

Replace the first `\"%@\"` in your values with literal `NULL` and remove the `NULL` from the format args, e.g:

```
NSString *momentInsertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MomentTbl (momentID, albumID, title, timestamp, author, latitude, longitude, canvas) VALUES (NULL, \"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", alb.ID, alb.title, m.timestamp, @"t-panda", m.latitude, m.longitude, m.moment];
```

Alternatively you could just leave out the primary key `momentID` altogether. sqlite inserts a  `NULL` in columns you didn't specify a value for.

Comment: After changing my code to what you said, the code returned by the NSLog is 101. SQLite's website says that is equivalent to SQLITE_DONE, but `if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)` is still evaluating to false.

Comment: Nevermind - removing the NSLog statement fixed that problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have two `sqlite3_step` calls without a `sqlite3_reset` in between.

The one in `NSLog` returns `101` (`SQLITE_DONE`), but the one in the if statement would probably return `SQLITE_MISUSE` (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).